# How can I change position of camera?

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, camera

I'm working on 3D game, where the player needs to complete 4 play fields called "homes" in level 1, then progress to level 2 which has 4 homes of its own.

In level 1, when the player completes the first home, how can I move the camera to the second home?

**Referance**:

[image: Scene view of 4 homes in level 1]
Gameover script on camera:

```
void fixedupdate()
{
 gameover();
}
void gameover()
{
     //some code here
    //camera position change but not move when my game over
    Vector3 positions = cams.transform.position + new Vector3(-12, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: `Vector3 positions` is just a temporary variable that Unity doesn't care about. Did you mean to assign this value to `cams.transform.position` to move the camera?

Comment: @DMGregory  thanks for given suggestion solved problem

Answer (score 1):

```
void gameover()
{
    Vector3 positions = cams.transform.position + new Vector3(-12, 0, 0);
}
```

This code creates a temporary variable called `positions` and assigns it a value 12 units to the left of the camera's position. It then does *nothing whatsoever* with that variable, and exits.

If you want to move the camera, then you can assign your new shifted position value to the camera's `transform.position` property:

```
void gameover()
{
    // Compute the new desired position for the camera in a temporary variable.
    Vector3 newPosition = cams.transform.position + new Vector3(-12, 0, 0);
    // Assign that position to the camera's transform to actually move it.
    cams.transform.position = newPosition;
}
```